# Check for over lapping dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got 4 dates `startDate`, `endDate`, `periodStartDate`, `periodEndDate`

And I need a method to return true if the period denoted by the `startDate` and `endDate` overlap the period denoted by the `periodStartDate` and `periodEndDate`.

This is C# 3.5 so can't use tuples. like the suggested link

My brain doesn't seem to be working so can somebody please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910617/multiple-date-range-comparison-for-overlap-how-to-do-it-efficiently

Comment: How would you explain it to a human, without using the word "between"? Write it down exactly that way! ;-)

Comment: Did you not find any of the answers helpful?

Comment: @Niklas no, not that just have been away from my desk. Am checking them now

Answer (score 3):

```
if (startDate<periodStartDate)//start date is older
{

   if (periodStartDate < endDate) //if end date is later than start of period
       return true;
   else return false; //
}
else //period start is older
{
    if (periodEndDate < startDate) //period ended before startdate
         return false;
    else
         return true;
}
```

just take care about where you want "<", and where "<="

edit (more elegant solution):

```
if (end1<start2) || (end2<start1) return false
else return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the end dates will always be equal or later than the start dates:

```
return startDate <= periodEndDate;
```

Comment: What? What if startDate < endDate < periodStartDate < periodEndDate ?

Comment: @Zecc - It would seem rather strange if there logic allowed the end dates to come before the start dates.

Comment: Period 2011-01-01 to 2011-02-01, Date 2010-01-01 to 2010-02-01. Your test will return true, but periods clearly dont overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check if the endDate is before periodStartDate or if the startDate is after the periodEndDate.
*(Assuming startDate < endDate and periodStartDate < periodEndDate)*

In code

```
if (endDate < periodStartDate || periodEndDate < startDate) return false;  
else return true;
```

or in visual =)

`startDate -------- endDate` `periodStartDate -------- periodEndDate`

`periodStartDate -------- periodEndDate` `startDate -------- endDate`

Comment: This is correct in the negative: if endDate <= periodStartDate, then {start->end} is before {periodStart->periodEnd}; if start >= periodStart, then {start->end} comes after {periodStart->periodEnd}. In all other cases they overlap.

Comment: I guess it could be argued whether the dates overlap or not if they are equal =)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want.

```
 {
            if (startDate < periodStartDate)
            {
                if (endDate>=periodStartDate)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }                             
            }
            else
            {
                if (startDate <= periodEndDate)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

This will catch the overlap even if one range complete encompasses the other.