# How to identify the maximum number of overlapping date ranges?

Tags: c#, date, date-range

This question might be similar to:

- [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)
- [Multiple Date range comparison for overlap: how to do it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910617/multiple-date-range-comparison-for-overlap-how-to-do-it-efficiently)

But, how can I get the maximum number of overlapping date ranges? (preferably in C#)

Example: (from - to)

```
01/01/2012 - 10/01/2012
03/01/2012 - 08/01/2012
09/01/2012 - 15/01/2012
11/01/2012 - 20/01/2012
12/01/2012 - 14/01/2012
```

Result = 3 maximum overlapping date ranges

**Solution**: Possible implementation of the solution proposed by @AakashM

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, int>> myTupleList = new List<Tuple<DateTime, int>>();

foreach (DataRow row in objDS.Tables[0].Rows) // objDS is a DataSet with the date ranges
{
    var myTupleFrom = new Tuple<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Parse(row["start_time"].ToString()), 1);
    var myTupleTo = new Tuple<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Parse(row["stop_time"].ToString()), -1);
    myTupleList.Add(myTupleFrom);
    myTupleList.Add(myTupleTo);
}

myTupleList.Sort();

int maxConcurrentCalls = 0;
int concurrentCalls = 0;
foreach (Tuple<DateTime,int> myTuple in myTupleList)
{
    if (myTuple.Item2 == 1)
    {
        concurrentCalls++;
        if (concurrentCalls > maxConcurrentCalls)
        {
            maxConcurrentCalls = concurrentCalls;
        }
    }
    else // == -1
    {
        concurrentCalls--;
    }
}
```

Where `maxConcurrentCalls` will be the maximum number of concurrent date ranges.

Comment: Do you mean "total number" by "maximum number" or may be the theoretical possible maximum number for a given number of ranges?

Comment: Maximum number. There are other 2 overlapping ranges, but I only care about the maximum number for this particular scenario

Comment: Now I know what you mean. You want to know the maximum number of ranges that overlap at the same date subrange. Here between 12/01 and 14/01 the three ranges (09/01-15/01), (11/01-20/01) and (12/01-14/01) do overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For each range, create two `Tuple<DateTime, int>`s with values `start, +1` and `end, -1`
- Sort the collection of tuples by date
- Iterate through the sorted list, adding the number part of the tuple to a running total, and keeping track of the maximum value reached by the running total
- Return the maximum value the running total reaches

Executes in `O(n log n)` because of the sort. There's probably a more efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please check the implementation added to the question