# Fast increment of many sub-spans of an array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, scipy

Is anyone familiar with a faster way to increment spans of indexes, as done by the following `patch(ar, ranges)`? In other words, it counts overlapping ranges, somewhat like a histogram. Maybe there is a vectorized method that already does something similar?

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.zeros(10)
ranges = [(1, 2), (4, 7), (6, 8)]
add_this = 1

def patch(ar, ranges):
    for start, end in ranges:
        ar[start:end] += add_this
    return ar

print np.arange(10)*1.
print patch(ar, ranges)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  2.  1.  0.  0.]
```

My problem is similar to: 
 - [Pandas: Overlapping time count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770939/pandas-overlapping-time-count)
 - [How to identify the maximum number of overlapping date ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956589/how-to-identify-the-maximum-number-of-overlapping-date-ranges?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such method in numpy, how every it's very easy to write a cython function to speedup the calculation:

Create the random range first:

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
idx = np.random.randint(0, N, (100000, 2)).astype(np.uint64)
idx.sort(axis=1)
tidx = [tuple(x) for x in idx.tolist()]
```

Python for loop:

```
%%time
a = np.zeros(N)
for s,e in tidx:
    a[s:e] += 1
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 459 ms, sys: 1e+03 µs, total: 460 ms
Wall time: 461 ms
```

define cython function:

```
%%cython
import cython

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def patch(double[::1] a, size_t[:, ::1] idx, double v):
    cdef size_t i, j
    for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
        for j in range(idx[i, 0], idx[i, 1]):
            a[j] += v
```

calculate by cython:

```
%%time
a2 = np.zeros(N)
patch(a2, idx, 1)
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 18 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 18 ms
Wall time: 17.7 ms
```

check results:

```
np.all(a == a2)
```

output:

```
True
```