# identify number of overlapping timespans in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of contracts with start and end dates.

How can I compute the number of overlapping contracts during the life span of a contracts?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'contract': pd.Series(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']),
    'start': pd.Series(['01/01/2015', '03/02/2015', '15/01/2015', '10/01/2015']),
    'end': pd.Series(['16/01/2015', '10/02/2015', '18/01/2015', '12/01/2015'])
})
```

which gives:

```
  contract         end       start
0       A1  16/01/2015  01/01/2015
1       A2  10/02/2015  03/02/2015
2       A3  18/01/2015  15/01/2015
3       A4  12/01/2015  10/01/2015
```

A1 overlaps with A3 and A4, therefore overlaps = 2.
A2 overlaps with no contract, therefore overlaps = 0.
A3 overlaps with A1, therefore overlaps = 1.
A4 overlaps with A1, therefore overlaps = 1.

I could just compare each time span (start to end) but that is `O(n**2)`
Any better idea?

I have the feeling an improvement could be gained by sorting and then [looping through the sorted ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956589/how-to-identify-the-maximum-number-of-overlapping-date-ranges)

Comment: To clarify: you have an n-long list of contracts. You want your output to be an n-long list of integers that indicates, for each input contract, how many other contracts they overlap with, right?

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @AndrewJanke: yes, as tagged.

Comment: A2 doesn't overlap with A3?

Comment: @JohnGalt: yes, it does. I fixed the example. tnx.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'contract': pd.Series(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']),
    'start': pd.Series(['01/01/2015', '03/02/2015', '15/01/2015', '10/01/2015']),
    'end': pd.Series(['16/01/2015', '10/02/2015', '18/01/2015', '12/01/2015'])
})
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start, dayfirst=True)
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end, dayfirst=True)

periods = df[['start', 'end']].apply(lambda x: (pd.date_range(x['start'], x['end']),), axis=1)
overlap = periods.apply(lambda col: periods.apply(lambda col_: col[0].isin(col_[0]).any()))
df['overlap_count'] = overlap[overlap].apply(lambda x: x.count() - 1, axis=1)
print df
```

Which yields:

```
  contract        end      start  overlap_count
0       A1 2015-01-16 2015-01-01              2
1       A2 2015-02-10 2015-02-03              0
2       A3 2015-01-18 2015-01-15              1
3       A4 2015-01-12 2015-01-10              1
```

I have updated the code to output the count of overlaps and not the overlap in days.