# Check if Time Range intersects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, algorithm, visual-studio-2012

I am currently developing a simple enrollment system in C# and I am thinking if there is a straightforward way to check if a certain time range (From - To) of my input session intersects with a time range in the database.

The scenario is as follows:

I have a table in my database named `tblSessionList` which stores different sessions per subject and I want to check each time the user adds a new session if a particular `Room` is occupied already in that particular time range. Technically, I want to check if the chosen time range does not conflict with the sessions in `tblSessionList`.

[image: Add Session Form]

`tblSessionList`

```
 | Subject Code |   Venue    |   Room   |        Date             |  From   |   To    |
 |              |            |          |                         |         |         |
 |   CRGOV401   |  GT Tower  | Room 3D  | Thursday, June 19, 2014 | 8:00 AM |10:00 AM |
 |   CRGOV401   |  GT Tower  | Room 59  | Sunday, June 29, 2014   | 1:00 PM |3:00  PM |
 |   GNBNK201   | Main Plaza | HR Hall  | Monday, June 30, 2014   | 9:00 AM |11:00 AM |
 |   GNBNK201   | Main Plaza | HR Hall  | Monday, June 30, 2014   | 1:00 PM |3:00     |
```

I have tried doing the following:

```
 private void btnAddSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool proceedCopy = true;

        DataTable timeHolder = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter selectTime = new SqlDataAdapter("select [From],[To] from tblSessionList where [Venue] = @venue and [Room] = @room", Connection.conn);
        selectTime.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@venue", venue.Text);
        selectTime.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", room.Text);

        selectTime.Fill(timeHolder);


        for(int i = 0; i < timeHolder.Rows.Count; i++)
       {

        if(timeHolder[i][0].toString() == From.Text) //checks if the 'From' of the query is the same with the 'From' of the new entry
              {
                MessageBox.Show("The room is already occupied on that time range");
                proceedCopy = false;
                break;
              }

        else if(timeHolder[i][1].toString() == To.Text) //checks if the 'To' of the query is the same with the 'To' of the new entry.
              {
                 MessageBox.Show("The room is already occupied on that time range");
                 proceedCopy = false;
                 break;
              }
        }
       if(proceedCopy == true)
           //insert code to insert new session to database here
    }
```

This is a hard-coded checking and this only checks the end points of the time range, not the time range itself. I'm thinking if there's a function in C# that I could use like Time only instead of DateTime.

Note: Every column in my database is a varchar. My apologies for having a dirty code for this is my first system ever.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods

Comment: Typically you would hand this off to the database as part of your query. Tip: Use EXISTS rather than COUNT in the query.

Comment: I'm quite not sure if it's applicable in my case but let me take time to analyze it but it is indeed a major help. Thank you! @JimMischel

Comment: Answered my question. Thank you!! @JimMischel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [interval tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/) to search on database . interval tree store a range (a,b) and builds a BST from it using comparison between  two intervals and decide whether it comes to left or right. The search on interval tree can be done in O(logn).