# PHP Determine when multiple(n) datetime ranges overlap each other

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having a hell of a time trying to solve the following problem:

It's a calendar program where given a set of available datetime sets from multiple people, I need to figure out what datetime ranges everyone is available in PHP

**Availability Sets:**

```
p1: start: "2016-04-30 12:00", end: "2016-05-01 03:00"

p2: start: "2016-04-30 03:00", end: "2016-05-01 03:00"

p3: start: "2016-04-30 03:00", end: "2016-04-30 13:31"
    start: "2016-04-30 15:26", end: "2016-05-01 03:00"
```

I'm looking for a function that I can call that will tell me what datetime ranges all (p) people are available at the same time.

In the above example the answer should be:

```
2016-04-30 12:00 -> 2016-04-30 13:31
2016-04-30 15:26 -> 2016-05-01 03:00
```

I did find this similar question and answer 
[Datetime -Determine whether multiple(n) datetime ranges overlap each other in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736000/datetime-determine-whether-multiplen-datetime-ranges-overlap-each-other-in-r)

But I have no idea what language that is, and have to unable to translate the logic in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are some bugs with this implementation, see the comments. I'm unable to delete it as it's the accepted answer. Please use iainn or fusion3k's very good answers until I get around to fixing it.**

There's actually no need to use any date/time handling to solve this
problem. You can exploit the fact that dates in this format are in alphabetical as well as chronological order.

I'm not sure this makes the solution any less complex. It's probably less
readable this way. But it's considerably faster than iterating over every minute so you might choose it if performance is a concern.

You also get to use
[every](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
[single](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
[array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
[function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
[out there](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), which is nice.

Of course, because I haven't used any date/time functions, it might not work if Daylight Savings Time or users in different time zones need dealing with.

```
$availability = [
    [
        ["2016-04-30 12:00", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["2016-04-30 03:00", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ],
    [
        ["2016-04-30 03:00", "2016-04-30 13:31"],
        ["2016-04-30 15:26", "2016-05-01 03:00"]
    ]
];

// Placeholder array to contain the periods when everyone is available.
$periods = [];

// Loop until one of the people has no periods left.
while (count($availability) &&
       count(array_filter($availability)) == count($availability)) {
    // Select every person's earliest date, then choose the latest of these
    // dates.
    $start = array_reduce($availability, function($carry, $ranges) {
        $start = array_reduce($ranges, function($carry, $range) {
            // This person's earliest start date.
            return !$carry ? $range[0] : min($range[0], $carry);
        });
        // The latest of all the start dates.
        return !$carry ? $start : max($start, $carry);
    });

    // Select each person's range which contains this date.
    $matching_ranges = array_filter(array_map(function($ranges) use($start) {
        return current(array_filter($ranges, function($range) use($start) {
            // The range starts before and ends after the start date.
            return $range[0] <= $start && $range[1] >= $start;
        }));
    }, $availability));

    // Find the earliest of the ranges' end dates, and this completes our
    // first period that everyone can attend.
    $end = array_reduce($matching_ranges, function($carry, $range) {
        return !$carry ? $range[1] : min($range[1], $carry);
    });

    // Add it to our list of periods.
    $periods[] = [$start, $end];

    // Remove any availability periods which finish before the end of this
    // new period.
    array_walk($availability, function(&$ranges) use ($end) {
        $ranges = array_filter($ranges, function($range) use($end) {
            return $range[1] > $end;
        });
    });
}

// Output the answer in the specified format.
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    echo "$period[0] -> $period[1]\n";
}
/**
 * Output:
 * 
 * 2016-04-30 12:00 -> 2016-04-30 13:31
 * 2016-04-30 15:26 -> 2016-05-01 03:00
 */
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Matt, clearly you have brilliant mind, and whilst it will take me some time to work out how exactly it works, it works like a charm.

Comment: @matt-raines can you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70786675/return-the-amount-of-overlapping-from-arraylist-of-date-intervals? I have used the above code in my case but it's not resolved.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya You're right, there was a bug. The exit condition wasn't quite right from the while loop. Have edited and should work now.

Comment: @MattRaines I have updated my question with the new bug. Can you help me?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it doesn't look like the code above works in all cases. Thanks for testing it :D but I'm afraid I haven't been able to fix it without making it much more complicated. I would try one of the other answers and if I get a chance to look at this question again some time, I will.

I would delete the answer but as it has been accepted, I am not able to. :(

Answer (score 5):

Well that was fun. There's probably a more elegant way of doing this than looping over every minute, but I don't know if PHP is the language for it. Note that this currently needs to manage the start and end times to search separately, although it would be fairly trivial to calculate them based on the available shifts.

```
<?php
$availability = [
    'Alex' => [
        [
            'start' => new DateTime('2016-04-30 12:00'),
            'end'   => new DateTime('2016-05-01 03:00'),
        ],
    ],

    'Ben' => [
        [
            'start' => new DateTime('2016-04-30 03:00'),
            'end'   => new DateTime('2016-05-01 03:00'),
        ],
    ],

    'Chris' => [
        [
            'start' => new DateTime('2016-04-30 03:00'),
            'end'   => new DateTime('2016-04-30 13:31')
        ],

        [
            'start' => new DateTime('2016-04-30 15:26'),
            'end'   => new DateTime('2016-05-01 03:00')
        ],
    ],
];

$start = new DateTime('2016-04-30 00:00');
$end   = new DateTime('2016-05-01 23:59');
$tick  = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 minute');

$period = new DatePeriod($start, $tick, $end);

$overlaps = [];
$overlapStart = $overlapUntil = null;

foreach ($period as $minute)
{
    $peopleAvailable = 0;

    // Find out how many people are available for the current minute
    foreach ($availability as $name => $shifts)
    {
        foreach ($shifts as $shift)
        {
            if ($shift['start'] <= $minute && $shift['end'] >= $minute)
            {
                // If any shift matches, this person is available
                $peopleAvailable++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If everyone is available...
    if ($peopleAvailable == count($availability))
    {
        // ... either start a new period...
        if (!$overlapStart)
        {
            $overlapStart = $minute;
        }

        // ... or track an existing one
        else
        {
            $overlapUntil = $minute;
        }
    }

    // If not and we were previously in a period of overlap, end it
    elseif ($overlapStart)
    {
        $overlaps[] = [
            'start' => $overlapStart,
            'end'   => $overlapUntil,
        ];

        $overlapStart = null;
    }
}

foreach ($overlaps as $overlap)
{
    echo $overlap['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), ' -> ', $overlap['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to set the start of the period just one minute before the earliest starting shift and the end to one minute after the latest ending time shift.

Comment: Fine. This can easily be changed to find if NO period are overlapping within a bunch of x periods of time

Comment: But it may consume ressources if considered period (earliest starting shift and latest shift end) is big (say days, months...)

Answer (score 2):

A different approach to your question is to use bitwise operators. The benefits of this solution are memory usage, speed and short code. The handicap is that — in your case — we can not use php integer, because we work with large numbers (1 day in minutes is 2<sup>24*60</sup>), so we have to use [GMP Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), that is not available by default in most php distribution. However, if you use [`apt-get`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html) or any other packages manager, the installation is [very simple](https://serverfault.com/questions/429585/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-ubuntu).

To better understand my approach, I will use an array with a total period of 30 minutes to simplify binary representation:

```
$calendar = 
[
    'p1' => [
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 12:00', 'end' => '2016-04-30 12:28']
    ],
    'p2' => [
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 12:10', 'end' => '2016-04-30 12:16'],
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 12:22', 'end' => '2016-05-01 12:30']
    ]
];
```

First of all, we find min and max dates of all array elements, then we init the free (time) variable with the difference in minutes between max and min. In above example (30 minutes), we obtain 2<sup>30</sup>-2<sup>0</sup>=1,073,741,823, that is a binary with 30 ‘1’ (or with 30 bits set):

```
111111111111111111111111111111
```

Now, for each person, we create the corresponding free-time variable with the same method. For the first person is easy (we have only one time interval): the difference between start and min is 0, the difference between end and min is 28, so we have 2<sup>28</sup>-2<sup>0</sup>=268435455, that is:

```
001111111111111111111111111111
```

At this point, we update global free time with a `AND` bitwise operation between global free time itself and person free time. The `OR` operator set bits if they are set in both compared values:

```
111111111111111111111111111111      global free time
001111111111111111111111111111      person free time
==============================
001111111111111111111111111111      new global free time
```

For the second person, we have two time intervals: we calculate each time interval with know method, then we compone global person free time using `OR` operator, that set bits if they are set in either first or second value:

```
000000000000001111110000000000      12:10 - 12:16
111111110000000000000000000000      12:22 - 12:30
==============================
111111110000001111110000000000      person total free time
```

Now we update global free time with the same method used for first person (`AND` operator):

```
001111111111111111111111111111      previous global free time
111111110000001111110000000000      person total free time
==============================
001111110000001111110000000000      new global free time
  └────┘      └────┘
  :28-:22     :16-:10
```

As you can see, at the end we have an integer with bits set only in minutes when everyone is available (you have to count starting from right). Now, you can convert back this integer to datetimes. Fortunately, `GMP` extension has a method to find 1/0 offset, so we can avoid to perform a for/foreach loop through all digits (that in real case are many more than 30).

---

Let's see the complete code to apply this concept to your array:

```
$calendar = 
[
    'p1' => [
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 12:00', 'end' => '2016-05-01 03:00']
    ],
    'p2' => [
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 03:00', 'end' => '2016-05-01 03:00']
    ],
    'p3' => [
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 03:00', 'end' => '2016-04-30 13:31'],
        ['start' => '2016-04-30 15:26', 'end' => '2016-05-01 03:00']
    ]
];

/* Get active TimeZone, then calculate min and max dates in minutes: */
$tz   = new DateTimeZone( date_default_timezone_get() );
$flat = call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $calendar );
$min  = date_create( min( array_column( $flat, 'start' ) ) )->getTimestamp()/60;
$max  = date_create( max( array_column( $flat, 'end' ) ) )->getTimestamp()/60;

/* Init global free time (initially all-free): */
$free = gmp_sub( gmp_pow( 2, $max-$min ), gmp_pow( 2, 0 ) );

/* Process free time(s) for each person: */
foreach( $calendar as $p )
{
    $pf = gmp_init( 0 );
    foreach( $p as $time )
    {
        $start = date_create( $time['start'] )->getTimestamp()/60;
        $end   = date_create( $time['end'] )->getTimestamp()/60;
        $pf = gmp_or( $pf, gmp_sub( gmp_pow( 2, $end-$min ), gmp_pow( 2, $start-$min ) ) );
    }
    $free = gmp_and( $free, $pf );
}

$result = [];
$start = $end = 0;

/* Create resulting array: */
while( ($start = gmp_scan1( $free, $end )) >= 0 )
{
    $end = gmp_scan0( $free, $start );
    if( $end === False) $end = strlen( gmp_strval( $free, 2 ) )-1;
    $result[] =
    [
        'start' => date_create( '@'.($start+$min)*60 )->setTimezone( $tz )->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
        'end'   => date_create( '@'.($end+$min)*60 )->setTimezone( $tz )->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
    ];
}

print_r( $result );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2016-04-30 12:00:00
            [end]   => 2016-04-30 13:31:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2016-04-30 15:26:00
            [end]   => 2016-05-01 03:00:00
        )
)
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/kboC7)**</kbd>

Some additional notes:

- At the start, we set `$tz` to current timezone: we will use it later, at the end, when we create final dates from timestamps. Dates created from timestamps are in UTC, so we have to set correct timezone.
- To retrieve initial `$min` and `$max` values in minutes, firstly we flat original array, then we retrieve min and max date using `array_column`.
- [`gmp_sub`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sub.php) subtract second argument from first argument, [`gmp_pow`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-pow.php) raise number (arg 1) into power (arg 2).
- In the final `while` loop, we use [`gmp_scan1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-scan1.php) and [`gmp_scan0`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-scan0.php) to retrieve each ‘111....’ interval, then we create returning array elements using `gmp_scan1` position for `start` key and `gmp_scan0` position for `end` key.

Comment: Hi fusion, i'm on a shared webhost, and doesn't look like I have access to installing that GMP Extension. Thankyou heaps for your in-depth reply you clearly are very knowledgeable in this stuff.