# Check if time fall under time ranges

Tags: php

I have this kind of scenario. Let say I have setting for overtime such as below. It can be in array.

```
Array     From       Until
[0]       5:00 AM    7:00 AM
[1]       6:00 PM    9:00 PM
```

Then, I will come to work to have an overtime. How to check if the actual overtime clocking is fall under the time range above?

For example, I come for overtime at:

```
OT Start: 6:00 AM , OT End: 9:00 AM
```

So, I will get

```
OT Start Allowed  OT End Allowed
6:00 AM           7:00 AM
```

For more scenario, if

```
OT Start     OT End     OT Start Allowed     OT End Allowed
4:00 AM      6:30 AM    5:00 AM              6:30 AM
5:30 AM      8:00 AM    5:30 AM              7:00 AM
5:30 PM      8:00 PM    6:00 PM              8:00 PM
6:30 PM      9:30 PM    6:30 PM              9:00 PM
5:30 PM      9:30 PM    6:00 PM              9:00 PM
5:30 AM      7:00 PM    5:30 AM              7:00 AM
                        6:00 PM              7:00 PM
6:00 AM      10:00 PM   6:00 AM              7:00 AM
                        6:00 PM              9:00 PM
```

That's how the system should handle the scenario. Anyone have idea how to do this in php? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please format your question, my eyes hurt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Determine when multiple(n) datetime ranges overlap each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868675/php-determine-when-multiplen-datetime-ranges-overlap-each-other)

Comment: I did look into the question and answers given. But still cannot relate them with my scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, this seems a bit more straightforward than the more general question. Answer to follow.

Comment: I think there's a fault in the second row of your desired output. `OT Start Allowed` should be `5:30 AM`?

Comment: @MattRaines yes..you are right. Edited to the correct one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each pair of time ranges, ie one range of allowed hours and the actual hours, you need to check that the actual period starts before the allowed period ends and ends after it starts (or possibly on or after, if this is the case substitute `>=` for `>`). Then you just take the latest start time and the earliest end time.

```
$permitted_hours = [["05:00", "07:00"], ["18:00", "21:00"]];

$claims = [["04:00", "06:30"], ["05:30", "08:00"], ["17:30", "20:00"],
    ["18:30", "21:30"], ["17:30", "21:30"], ["05:30", "19:00"], ["06:00", "22:00"]];

echo "OT Start  OT End  OT Start Allowed  OT End Allowed\n";
foreach ($claims as $claim) {
    $first_match = true;
    echo "$claim[0]     $claim[1]   ";
    foreach ($permitted_hours as $permitted) {
        if ($claim[0] < $permitted[1] && $claim[1] > $permitted[0]) {
            if (!$first_match) {
                echo "\n                  ";
            }
            $start = max($permitted[0], $claim[0]);
            $end = min($permitted[1], $claim[1]);
            echo "$start             $end";
            $first_match = false;
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
/*
OT Start  OT End  OT Start Allowed  OT End Allowed
04:00     06:30   05:00             06:30
05:30     08:00   05:30             07:00
17:30     20:00   18:00             20:00
18:30     21:30   18:30             21:00
17:30     21:30   18:00             21:00
05:30     19:00   05:30             07:00
                  18:00             19:00
06:00     22:00   06:00             07:00
                  18:00             21:00
*/
```

Comment: It took 4 days for me to figure out on how to do this, but you took only 4 minutes to knock me with the answer I've been looking for. Brilliant, great effort, and many thanks! :)