# Return the amount of overlapping from arraylist of date intervals

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have the following array named **$all_data**.

```
Array
(
[Chevenez] => Array
    (
        [41.NEwan0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [41.NEwan1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [42.NEwan0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [42.NEwan1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-09 04:13:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459
                    )

            )

    )

[Barcelona] => Array
    (
        [5.NEwan0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [5.NEwan1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [16.NEwan0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
                    )

            )

        [16.NEwan1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459
                        [1] => 2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

From the above array, I am trying to get overlapping time intervals for **Chevenez** and **Barcelona**. Let's say for **Chevenez** if all keys **41.NEwan0, 41.NEwan1, 42.NEwan0 and 42.NEwan1** has overlap then only consider otherwise not.

I have tried the idea presented at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868675/php-determine-when-multiplen-datetime-ranges-overlap-each-other).

```
// Placeholder array to contain the periods when everyone is available.
$periods = [];

foreach($all_data as $key => $data){
    // Loop until one of the people has no periods left.
    while (count($data) && count(array_filter($data)) == count($data)) {
        // Select every person's earliest date, then choose the latest of these
        // dates.
        $start = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $ranges) {
            $start = array_reduce($ranges, function($carry, $range) {
                // This person's earliest start date.
                return !$carry ? $range[0] : min($range[0], $carry);
            });
            // The latest of all the start dates.
            return !$carry ? $start : max($start, $carry);
        });

        // Select each person's range which contains this date.
        $matching_ranges = array_filter(array_map(function($ranges) use($start) {
            return current(array_filter($ranges, function($range) use($start) {
                // The range starts before and ends after the start date.
                return $range[0] <= $start && $range[1] >= $start;
            }));
        }, $data));

        // Find the earliest of the ranges' end dates, and this completes our
        // first period that everyone can attend.
        $end = array_reduce($matching_ranges, function($carry, $range) {
            return !$carry ? $range[1] : min($range[1], $carry);
        });

        // Add it to our list of periods.
        $periods[$key][] = [$start, $end];

        // Remove any availability periods which finish before the end of this
        // new period.
        array_walk($data, function(&$ranges) use ($end) {
            $ranges = array_filter($ranges, function($range) use($end) {
                return $range[1] > $end;
            });
        });
    }
}

// Output the answer in the specified format.
foreach ($periods as $key => $period) {
    foreach ($period as $period1) {
        echo "$key : $period1[0] -> $period1[1]\n";
    }
}
```

But it gives me the below output.

```
Chevenez : 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
Barcelona : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
```

but my desired output is.

```
Chevenez : 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
Barcelona : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
```

It gives me **Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459** in second line but it should be **Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459**

@amirreza-noori I am getting errors for following arrry.

```
$all_data = [ 
'Chevenez' => [
    '41.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459'],
                            ['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
    '41.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459'], 
                            ['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
    '42.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459'], 
                            ['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
    '42.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459'], 
                            ['2022-01-09 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
    '43.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
    '43.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
    '44.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
    '44.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:28:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
],

'Barcelona' => [
    '5.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459']],
    '5.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459']],
    '16.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459']],
    '16.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459']]
]
];
```

and desired output for it is.

```
Chevenez : 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
Barcelona : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
```

Comment: I've fixed and edited the answer in the original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Determine when multiple(n) datetime ranges overlap each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868675/php-determine-when-multiplen-datetime-ranges-overlap-each-other)

Comment: @matt-raines I've updated the question with a new code but still has some issues.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it doesn't look like the code in my answer to the other question works in all cases. Thanks for testing it :D but I'm afraid I haven't been able to fix it without making it much more complicated. I would try one of the other answers and if I get a chance to look at this question again some time, I will.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand something if all keys has overlap Then consider what ?
(In your question) :
Let's say for Chevenez if all keys 41.NEwan0, 41.NEwan1, 42.NEwan0 and 42.NEwan1 has overlap then only consider otherwise not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the way you treat the dates. So there's no need to convert them to the float number. So the question is about algorithms. The following code could be a solution.

```
$all_data = [ 
    'Chevenez' => [
        '41.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459'],
                                ['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
        '41.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459'], 
                                ['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
        '42.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459'], 
                                ['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
        '42.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459'], 
                                ['2022-01-09 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
        '43.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
        '43.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
        '44.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
        '44.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:28:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
    ],

    'Barcelona' => [
        '5.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459']],
        '5.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459']],
        '16.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459']],
        '16.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459']]
    ]
];

$periods = [];

foreach($all_data as $place => $parts) {
    // select first times of each place
    $part1_times = $parts[array_key_first($parts)];
    $periods[$place] = [];
    
    // walk on times parts
    foreach($part1_times as $t => $part1_time_range) {
        $range_low = $part1_time_range[0];        
        $range_up = $part1_time_range[1];
        
        // detect common range
        foreach($parts as $part_times) {
            if(!isset($part_times[$t])) break;
            $rlow = $part_times[$t][0];
            $rup = $part_times[$t][1];
            
            if($rlow > $range_low) $range_low = $rlow;
            if($rup < $range_up) $range_up = $rup;          
        }
        
        if($range_low < $range_up) $periods[$place][] = [$range_low, $range_up];
    }
    
    // sort times in each place from small to big
    usort($periods[$place], function($a, $b) {
        return $a[0] > $b[0] ? 1 : -1;
    });
}


// Output the answer in the specified format.
foreach ($periods as $key => $periods) {
    foreach ($periods as $period) {
        echo "$key : $period[0] -> $period[1]\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chevenez : 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
Barcelona : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
```

Comment: I am getting errors for other cases and I have updated the question regarding that

Comment: Sorry, for the half info Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459 should not be in result for updated array

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya The answer is edited based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a bunch of nested loops

```
$output = [];
foreach ($all_data as $place => $place_data) {
    foreach ($place_data as $innerplace_data) {
        $canBeAdded = true;
        foreach ($all_data as $otherplace => $otherplace_data) {
            if ($place !== $otherplace) {
                foreach($otherplace as $innerotherplace_data) {
                    $canBeAdded = $canBeAdded && (!(($innerotherplace_data[0] > $otherplace_data[1]) || ($innerotherplace_data[1] < $otherplace_data[0])));
                }
            }
        }
        if ($canBeAdded) $output[]=$place . " " . $innerplace_data[0] . "->" . $innerplace_data[1];
    }
}
```

Untested.

Comment: I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$innerplace_data' error

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya thanks for pointing that out! There was a typo in my code, which was fixed since then. Is it working better now?

Comment: I am still getting error on "foreach($otherplace as $innerotherplace_data) {" this line

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya will look into this and will respond afterwards (later today). Thanks!

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya I had some difficulty in writing a proper test case. Unfortunately I cannot afford too much time into this. Can you provide an input array that is syntactically legal? Your array in the question can be understood, but it's syntactically illegal. If you could build a PHP array that can be used as an input, that would be great. If you do a `json_encode`, converting your array into a JSON and show me the result, that could also work, because then I would do a `json_decode` to get the proper PHP input to test with.

Answer (score 0):

You Find down below my solution for you. well tested:

```
class TimeSlots {


    private array $cities;

    private array $values;

    private array $overlaps;

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->setData($data);
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function setData($data): void {
        $this->cities = array_keys($data);
        $this->overlaps = [];
        $this->values = array_map("array_values", array_values($data));
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function clear(): void {
        $this->values = [];
        $this->cities = [];
    }

    public function getOverlaps(): array {

        if (!empty($this->overlaps)) {
            return $this->overlaps;
        }

        $result = [];
        if (empty($this->cities)) {
            return $result;
        }

        foreach ($this->cities as $position => $city) {
            $computed = $this->computeCityOverlap($position);
            $result[$city] = $computed;
        }

        $this->overlaps = $result;
        return $this->overlaps;
    }

    private function computeCityOverlap(int $pos): array {

        $current = 0;    

        return array_reduce($this->values[$pos],function ($carry, $ranges) use ($pos,&$current) {

            foreach ($ranges as $index => $range) {
                $allRangesFlat = array_filter(array_map(function ($value) use ($index) {
                    return $value[$index] ?? null;
                }, $this->values[$pos]));
            //Don't include current range
                array_splice($allRangesFlat, $current, 1);

                $overlap = $this->inspectOverlap($allRangesFlat, $range);
                if (empty($overlap)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(empty($carry[$index])){
                    $carry[$index] = [];
                }

                if(empty($start = $carry[$index][0]) || ( $overlap[0] >= max($start, $range[0]))){
                    $carry[$index][0] = $overlap[0];
                }

                if(empty($end = $carry[$index][1]) || ($overlap[1] >= max($end,  $range[1]) )){
                    $carry[$index][1] = $overlap[1];
                }

            }

            $current += 1;
            return $carry;
        }, []);
    }

    private function inspectOverlap(array $haystack, array $range): array{

        if (empty($range[0]) || empty($range[1])) {
            return [];
        }

        $result = array_reduce($haystack, function ($carry, $val) use ($range) {
            if (empty($val[0]) || empty($val[1])) {
                return $carry;
            }

            if ($val[0] >= $range[0] && $val[0] <= $range[1]){

                $end =  min($range[1] , $val[1]);
                if (empty($carry[0]) || ($carry[0] >= $val[0] && $carry[0] <= $val[1])) {
                    $carry[0] = $val[0];
                    $carry[1] =  $carry[1] ? min($end,  $carry[1]) : $end;
                }
            }elseif (($val[1] >= $range[0] && $val[1] <= $range[1])){

                $start = max($val[0], $range[0]);
                if (empty($carry[1]) || ($carry[1] <= $val[1] && $carry[1] >= $val[0])) {
                    $carry[1] = $val[1];
                    $carry[0] =  $carry[0] ? min($start,  $carry[0]) : $start;
                }
            }

            return $carry;
        }, [null, null]);

        return array_filter($result);
    }
}

$all_data = [
    'Chevenez' => [
        '41.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459'],
            ['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
        '41.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459'],
            ['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
        '42.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459'],
            ['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
        '42.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459'],
            ['2022-01-09 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
        '43.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:53:37.49459']],
        '43.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:23:37.49459']],
        '44.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-09 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459']],
        '44.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-09 04:28:37.49459', '2022-01-09 05:13:37.49459']],
    ],

    'Barcelona' => [
        '5.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 03:53:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:53:37.49459']],
    '    5.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:23:37.49459']],
        '16.NEwan0' => [['2022-01-19 04:03:37.49459', '2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459']],
        '16.NEwan1' => [['2022-01-19 04:13:37.49459', '2022-01-19 05:13:37.49459']]
    ]
];

$slots = new TimeSlots($all_data);
$o = $slots->getOverlaps();
foreach ($o as $city => $periods) {
    foreach ($periods as $period1) {
        echo "$city : $period1[0] -> $period1[1]" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Chevenez : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
Chevenez : 2022-01-09 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-09 04:33:37.49459
Barcelona : 2022-01-19 04:23:37.49459 -> 2022-01-19 04:33:37.49459
```