# How do I determine if two leave requests (time off) conflict (overlap)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an HR system and I need to see if the new leave (time off) request conflicts with an existing one. I have done this based on the entire day, but I need to do the comparison based on half days...

Here is my data structure (and the data format) This is all done in SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
StartDate     (datetime)
EndDate       (datetime)
'The following 2 variables show if the user is taking a half or a full day off. 
'The options for each are listed and explained.

StartDateAMPM (int) 0=All Day (StartDate may or may not be the same as the EndDate), 
                    1=AM, (User is out of the office only in the morning)
                    2=PM  (User is out of the office only in the afternoon)

EndDateAMPM   (int) 0="All Day" / "half day" / "StartDate = EndDate", 
                    1=AM (The user is off for the morning only)
                     **NOTE This cannot be PM (as you cannot end a leave
                            with a half day in the afternoon)
                     **IF this is a "0", there are 3 possibilities --
                      A) a full day leave where the StartDate <> EndDate
                      B) a full day where the StartDate = EndDate
                      C) a partial day where StartDate = EndDate and the user
                              is off in the morning or the afternoon
```

So I pass this info to the DB and am trying to see if the new leave conflicts with existing leave... Here is the code to do it for a single day:

```
Legend:  @Start DateTime -- StartDate from new leave
         @end   DateTime -- EndDate from new leave
         @StartDateAMPM (int) 0,1,2 (see above for details)
         EndDateAMPM    (int) 0,1   (see above for details)

select count(ID)  from v_VacReqWHalfDays 
where 
  ( @Start BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate 
OR  @End   BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate 
OR (@Start <= StartDate and @End >=EndDate))
and kUserID = @UserID
```

If Count(ID) > 0, there is a conflict --

**My question is how to incorporate the 1/2 day leave...** (people can take full days or half days off (the morning or the afternoon).

I want to use TSQL to determine if the current leave request conflicts (overlaps) with an existing and can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: The general check for an overlap is: `Start1 <= End2 and Start2 <= End1`.

Comment: This doesn't work if the date ranges are identical!!! Check it out... let me know if I'm wrong... that happened once ;-)

Comment: `declare @Start1 as Date = '19960218', @End1 as Date = '19960315';
declare @Start2 as Date = @Start1, @End2 as Date = @End1;
select @Start1 as Start1, @End1 as End1, @Start2 as Start2, @End2 as End2, case when @Start1 <= @End2 and @Start2 <= @End1 then 'overlap' else 'no overlap' end as Status;` Perhaps you had an issue with `DATETIME` values that didn't have matching times.

Comment: I realize where my logic failed me... yes... the solution linked is AWESOME!!!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has been asked and answered... 
 [Algorithm to detect overlapping periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods) ... 
Thanks all... this is a dup question. Please disregard... I realize I should add the actual time stamp of the leave... to my Start and End Dates and do a simple compare -- I wish I had figured this out months ago... would have saved me much pain and suffering...

```
My new startDate will be recorded as "08/22/2015 09:00:00.000" 
                          instead of "08/22/2015 00:00:00.000"  
and the endDate will be              "08/23/2015 13:00:00.000" 
                          instead of "08/23/2015 00:00:00.000"  
I can then compare as per the linked ticket:
```