# Overlapping List of Objects

Tags: c#, linq, comparison

I have the following

`var list = new List<Schedule>();`

`Schedule` object has the following properties:

- StartTime (DateTime)
- EndTime (DateTime)

Is there a one-line piece of code that can check if the time constraints overlap in `list` while iterating through all its `Schedule` members?

Thanks in advance.

> I'm trying to have the logic of the above in a method called `EnforceOverlapPolicy()` that technically would throw a new exception if there are any conflicts.

Comment: StartTime and EndTime are values of Time in the same day?

Comment: @Steve yes always. For every object in that `List<Schedule>` is on the same day. - Actually I'm parsing the time only ignoring the actual `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is whether an overlap exists and not which schedules overlap then you should be able to do this in O(n log n).  The key is to sort the schedules by their `StartTime` and `EndTime` (the O(n log n) part).  Then you can enumerate the result and compare each schedule's `StartTime` to the previous schedule's `EndTime`.  If the `StartTime` is earlier than the `EndTime` then you have overlapping schedules.  I do not think it can be done in a single query, however, without some third party help.  I am a fan of `Ix-Main` myself.  The following solution uses the `Buffer` function from `Ix-Main`:

```
bool hasOverlap =
    list
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartTime)
    .ThenBy(x => x.EndTime)
    .Buffer(2, 1)
    .Where(x => x.Count == 2)
    .Where(x => x[1].StartTime < x[0].EndTime)
    .Any();
```

If you do not want to use third party libraries then you can do the same thing with the following:

```
Schedule first = null;
bool hasOverlap = false;
using(var enumerator = list.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ThenBy(x => x.EndTime).GetEnumerator())
{
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    first = enumerator.Current;
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if(enumerator.Current.StartTime < first.EndTime)
        {
            hasOverlap = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `hasOverlapTwo` used for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming performance is not an issue (otherwise consider [an algorithm for overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods)):

```
var pairs = from f in list 
            from s in list
            where (f.EndTime < s.StartTime) && (f.StartTime < s.EndTime) && (f != s)
            select new {First = f, Second = s };
```

Basically, we're checking all possible pairs for overlap.

Alternatively, without query syntax:

```
var overlaps = list.SelectMany(l => list, (f, s) => new {f,s})
    .Where(x => (x.f.EndTime < x.s.StartTime) && 
               (x.f.StartTime < x.s.EndTime) && (x.f != x.s));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Can you please explain a bit how this works? I'm not sure but this seems to check for two Schedule objects in a given list, correct?

Comment: @user1027620 `from f in list from s in list` gives all possible combinations of pairs from `list`, then we check them for overlap by checking to see if their durations intersect. This is an O(n^2) solution but should be sufficient for relatively small (< 100000 items) lists.

Comment: Your answer seems pretty identical to the link you added with your answer. Why not mark it as duplicate?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov because OP is looking for a simple one liner way, and that question is looking for an efficient algorithm. So they're asking a different question about the same problem.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Perhaps you can enlighten OP with the optimal solution, he might change his mind about the one-liner :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I linked to that other post, that's why I did so :)

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but the poster doesn't ask to retrieve the overlaps, but to throw an exception if there is just one overlap. This could lead to a consistent optimization right?

Comment: @Steve correct. - `overlaps` in this case seems to always return `Enumeration yielded no results` even tho there are obvious conflicts. `Schedule 1` -> `EndTime: {9/27/2015 11:59:59 PM}` - `StartTime: {9/27/2015 12:00:00 AM}`. `Schedule 2` -> `EndTime: {9/27/2015 11:59:59 PM}` - `StartTime: {9/27/2015 2:00:00 AM}`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There is an extra parenthesis in your alternative solution that breaks the value of `x` -> .Where(x => x.f.EndTime < x.s.StartTime`)`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach and I am not sure of the performance of the whole thing, but the idea is to flatten out the ranges defined by your schedules in a BitArray that signals if a specific minute has been already used by a previous schedule.

Technically it is also not a 'one liner' answer albeit from the stand point of the calling code it is just one line

So suppose to have defined a class ScheduleList

```
public class ScheduleList : List<Schedule>
{
    private BitArray ba = new BitArray(1440);

    // Define own Add method to Add a Schedule to the list
    // Or override the predefined one....
    public Schedule Add(int sh, int sm, int eh, int em)
    {
        Schedule s = new Schedule();
        s.StartTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, sh, sm, 0);
        s.EndTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, eh, em, 0);

        // Of course, having full control on the Add phase, you
        // could easily enforce your policy at this point. 
        // You could not accept a new schedule if the time slot is busy
        // but we could ignore it at this point

        this.Add(s);
        return s;
    }

    public bool IsTimeSlotBusy(Schedule s)
    {
        int sidx = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((s.StartTime.Hour * 60) + s.StartTime.Minute).TotalMinutes);
        int eidx = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes((s.EndTime.Hour * 60) + s.EndTime.Minute).TotalMinutes);
        for (int x = sidx; x <= eidx; x++)
        {
            if (ba.Get(x)) return true;
            ba.Set(x, true);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

now you could write something like this

```
ScheduleList schedules = new ScheduleList();
schedules.Add(12, 0, 12, 30);
schedules.Add(15, 10, 15, 30);
schedules.Add(12, 0, 23, 59);
schedules.Add(14, 0, 23, 59);

// The fake 'one liner'
bool overlap = schedules.Any(s => schedules.IsTimeSlotBusy(s));
Console.WriteLine(overlap);
```

Waiting for the mathematicians here to show me why this is worst. (Not ironic, I really wish to know if this is bad from a mathematical point of view)

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks for the answer. Could you please explain a bit more about why the `BitArray` is needed? and why are the values split as such `sh, sm, eh, em` rather than directly `DateTime`? I'm sorry I didn't mention that the values will be retrieved from a `DateTimePicker` With the `Time` value visible only. I like you approach tbh but I'd like to understand more. Thanks again! - One more thing, I'd like to Compare `TotalSeconds` rather than Hours and Minutes directly is this possible with your solution?

Comment: A single bit on the 1440 bits array represent the busy state of a minute of the day (60*24). True if it has already been used by a schedule, false otherwise. Adding seconds requires to enlarge the array to 86400 bits (60*24*60) to represents each second. This could be a lot more of checks and probably not a good solution. You need to check against real data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool DoesNotOverlap(List<Schedule> timeSlots)
{
    DateTime endPrior = DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (Schedule timeSlot in timeSlots.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime))
    {
        if (timeSlot.StartTime > timeSlot.EndTime || timeSlot.StartTime < endPrior)
            return false;
        endPrior = timeSlot.End;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For whoever needs this, it's not a one liner as the question requests but it is simple approach that solves the issue of **checking for overlapping DateTime elements with Start and End date**

1. Sort the list using `OrderBy Linq` operator.
2. Do not allow the beginning `DateTime` to be more than the ending `DateTime`.
3. Track the end of each previous meeting to see if it overlaps within
   the next start of the scheduled `DateTime`.