# Elegant algorithm to detect overlapping periods with unbounded ends

Tags: algorithm, date, overlap

My question is the same as [Algorithm to detect overlapping periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods).
But in my case, a period can be **unbouded** (No End Date, ie. NULL).
I can't find an elegant way do to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unbounded end dates, you could also do something like:

```
a.end = a.end == NULL  ? MAXDATE : a.end;
b.end = b.end == NULL  ? MAXDATE : b.end;
bool overlap = a.start < b.end && b.start < a.end;
```

Or this could work:

```
bool overlap = (a.start < b.end || b.end == NULL) && (b.start < a.end || a.end == NULL);
```

Comment: Nice ! I did the first solution didn't find it really clean. I accept the second one. Thank you