# Comparing Custom Dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Question**
I would like to build a Power BI report that would allow the user to compare two date ranges of their choosing.
**Scenario**
Say, for example, we have a promotional event that ran from 3/5/18 to 3/7/18.  This event is similar to one that we ran previously, but not as part of the Year-over-Year dates.

I would like my users to be able to select the custom date range to compare with this year's event, let's say 2/13/17 - 2/15/17.

It seems like this is something that Power BI was born to do, but I've not been able to come up with a solution.  Is this feasible using Power BI?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can't you just use a date slicer or two?

Comment: You need to determine if date ranges overlap using a slicer.  PowerBi hasn't solved this (yet) but you can mimic it with filters.  See my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465016/819019 - I looked at this a few months back.  I still need to write this but work and home life get in the way :)