# Get the Common time between 2 DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime

I can get the Hours/Minutes/Seconds **difference** between 2 DateTime.

But I am trying to get the **common** time between 2 datetime, but not.

Example:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Here I am added the times.

```
 var list = new List<Meeting>();
        list.Add(
            new Meeting 
            { 
                Start = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 09:00 AM"), 
                End = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 10:00 AM")
            }
        );
        list.Add(
            new Meeting 
            { 
                Start = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 09:45 AM"), 
                End = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 10:30 AM") 
            }
        );
```

So, here I am trying to get the commont time between 2 lists.

The common time is **15** Minutes and the Time is **9:45 AM to 10:00 AM**.

So, any suggestions to get the time **9:45 AM to 10:00 AM**.

Comment: So to confirm my understanding - you want to find the `overlap` between two time periods.  If this is correct, you should adjust your question accordingly to avoid confusion and help you get a speedier answer.

Comment: What you mean is: I want to get the amount of time the two Meeting object's dates are in collision with each other in?

Comment: this is the better link to mark as duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods

Comment: @Svenmarim No, that doesn't give the date ranges.

Comment: truee.. truee..

Answer (score 3):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but it seems like you want to get the overlapping time interval.  I think something like this should work:

```
DateTime s1 = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 09:00 AM");
DateTime e1 = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 10:00 AM");
DateTime s2 = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 09:45 AM");
DateTime e2 = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2018 10:30 AM");

DateTime overlapStart = (s1 > s2 ? s1 : s2);
DateTime overlapEnd = (e1 < e2 ? e1 : e2);

TimeSpan overlappedTimeSpan 
    = (overlapStart < overlapEnd ? overlapEnd - overlapStart : TimeSpan.FromTicks(0));
```

Comment: To reject non-overlapping ranges you can add an additional check: `if (overlapStart < overlapEnd) ...` - or check if `overlappedTimeSpan` is negative.

Comment: Still working on it...bear with me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- There I think that takes care of it.

Comment: @rory.ap I can get difference of Minutes. How can get Common/Unique time of 9:45 AM to 10:00 AM.

Comment: My answer has that.  `overlapStart` above is 9:45 AM and `overlapEnd` is 10:00 AM.