# How to compare two period dates in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, boolean-logic

```
class Period {
   public DateTime Start { get; set; }
   public DateTime End { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm having difficulty with boolean logic of comparing two Period objects

Suppose in DB I have the following Period object.

```
var periodInDb = new Period { 
   Start = DateTime.ParseExact("2022-12-18", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   End = DateTime.ParseExact("2023-01-11", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
};
```

I want to only add a new period if it doesn't fall in between the period above.

I have written out on paper some type of scenario dates that might get added, I might have missed some scenarios:

**Start: 2022/12/18 

End: 2023/01/11**

Some scenario dates:

**Start**: 2022/12/19 ✔️
**End**: 2023/01/10 ❌
`------------------`
❌ Don't add because `end date` falls between between `2022/12/18 - 2023/01/11`

---

**Start**: 2022/12/19 ✔️
**End**: 2023/01/12 ✔️
`------------------`
❌ Don't add because `start date` falls between `2022/12/18 - 2023/01/11`

---

**Start**: 2022/12/17 ✔️
**End**: 2023/01/12 ✔️
`------------------`
❌ Don't add because part of `start date and end date` falls outside of `2022/12/18 - 2023/01/11`

**Start**: 2022/12/16 ✔️
**End**: 2023/12/17 ✔️
`------------------`
✔️ Add because `start date and end date` falls outside of `2022/12/18 - 2023/01/11`

How would I know if a period falls outside of another period?

Comment: I'd suggest to use this library which makes this trival and keeps your code readable: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: `2022-13-18`? When is that?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I meant `2022-12-18`

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate, this is `date range compared to date range`, and not `date range compared to datetime`?

Comment: It is not the right duplicate, but it is a duplicate of [this (*Algorithm to detect overlapping periods*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods) which was already marked as a duplicate of [that (*Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool HasOverlap(Period p1, Period p2)
{
    return p1.End >= p2.Start && p1.Start <= p2.End;
}
```

Comment: This. Note that depending on OP's specs, inequalities could be strict, but the logic is good here